# how to get the last updated table information in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

how to get the last updated table information in magento.

For Example:
I have created a new user account say name:XXX and PW:XXX. i need that information or get the recent update table information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
$collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect(*)
    ->addAttributeToSort('updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->getSelect()->limit(1);

$customer = $collection->load();
```

Comment: i have tried but error below i used u r code                            <?php

$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8888/e-commerce/api/soap/?wsdl',array('trace' => TRUE));

$session = $client->login('admin', 'admin12345');

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
$collection->
    ->addAttributeToSelect(*)
    ->addAttributeToSort('updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->getSelect()->limit(1);

$customer = $collection->load();
echo '$customer';
?>

Comment: error Msg:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\e-comm\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\lastUD.php on line 9

Answer (score 0):

Just crate a table format like following

```
------------------------------------------
id (auto increment) |  name    |   PW
------------------------------------------
```

and use this following code

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC
```